# Pass hidden information using ASP DataGrid HyperlinkColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, hyperlink

I have already implemented something in a `DataGrid` to pass a value to the target page:

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn HeaderText="Name"
DataTextField="Name"
DataNavigateUrlField="ID" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="UserManagement.aspx?ID={0}"
SortExpression="Name" />
```

I'm using the `ID` value on the next page in an SQL query.  But it's possible to just enter the page directly with any old value and get data from the DB.  I want to hide that value to prevent that security problem.  Is there a way to do something like that through the ASP classes in the code above, or do I just need to create some kind of click event handler to pass the values without showing them?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but it might be easier to implement and maintain, as well as be more secure, to just check whether the logged in user has access to the ID passed into UserManagement.aspx on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Store ID array in viewstate and pass array index as url parameter and get the value from viewstate in the UserManagement page.

Answer (score 1):

you can store the id value in the session to retrieve it later. It can be an session array or just a session variable based on your requirement.